# What if a Kafka broker cannot connect to zookeeper?

Tags: apache-kafka

If I have, say, 3 partitions with replication factor 3. Now what I understood is that they have all to connect to the same zookeeper. Ok what if they can't due to network issues ? Will the replication continue when the network is avaialble again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If ZK is down, your Kafka cluster will have limited functionality. For details, see [How does Kafka depend on Zookeeper?](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-HowdoesKafkadependonZookeeper?)

Answer (score 1):

Kafka requires Zookeeper (ZK). If ZK is down, then the entire Kafka cluster will be "down" (meaning: will be almost unusable). ZK is used for a bunch of things like managing internal topics etc.

If ZK becomes available to the Kafka cluster, the cluster will be operational.

Comment: "If ZK is down, then the entire Kafka cluster will be down" -> not entirely true. However, functionality will be limited until you restore ZK quorum.